# Android 10: java.lang.SecurityException: getDeviceId: The user 10222 does not meet the requirements to access device identifiers

Tags: java, android, permissions, android-10.0

I have a problem with Android 10. I have I'm getting this error when the user tries to give the Read Phone state permission. I know , that now Google restrict using the device id. Also , I have read all documentation regarding these changes, and my questions are other.

Firstly, let me describe how and for what I used the device id.

In the manifest.

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
```

And in the Java code.

```
 public String getDeviceId(boolean encrypt) {
        @SuppressLint("HardwareIds") String deviceId = android.provider.Settings.Secure.getString(activity.getContentResolver(), android.provider.Settings.Secure.ANDROID_ID);
        String encryptedDeviceId = "";
        if (encrypt) {
            try {
                encryptedDeviceId = MCrypt.bytesToHex(MCrypt.$().encrypt(deviceId));
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        return encryptedDeviceId;
    }
```

Now , I know that I can't get the device id.
Here are my questions.

1.Event If I remove the uses_permission row in manifest and remove the java code, my app continues to want the Phone State permission. Why? 
Here is my whole manifest.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="myoackagenamehere"
    android:installLocation="preferExternal"
    android:versionCode="151"
    android:versionName="1.5.1">
    <uses-feature android:glEsVersion="0x00020000" android:required="true" />
    <supports-screens
        android:anyDensity="true"
        android:largeScreens="true"
        android:normalScreens="true"
        android:smallScreens="true"
        android:xlargeScreens="true" />

    <uses-permission android:name="com.android.vending.CHECK_LICENSE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.android.vending.BILLING" />
    <uses-permission android:name="org.onepf.openiab.permission.BILLING" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.sec.android.iap.permission.BILLING" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.nokia.payment.BILLING" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.slideme.sam.manager.inapp.permission.BILLING" />

    <permission
        android:name="mypackagename.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />
    <uses-permission android:name="mypackagename.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />

    <application
        android:name="androidx.multidex.MultiDexApplication"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:roundIcon="@drawable/ic_launcher_round"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:fullBackupContent="true"
        tools:replace="android:name,android:fullBackupContent"
        android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen">
        <activity
            android:name="mypackagename.MainActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|locale|screenSize"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="landscape"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysHidden">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
                <data android:scheme="@string/apps_flyer_deep_link" />
            </intent-filter>

        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name="com.ironsource.sdk.controller.ControllerActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
            android:hardwareAccelerated="true" />
        <activity
            android:name="com.ironsource.sdk.controller.InterstitialActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
            android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent" />
        <activity
            android:name="com.ironsource.sdk.controller.OpenUrlActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
            android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent" />

        <activity
            android:name="com.vungle.warren.ui.VungleActivity"
            android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize|screenLayout|smallestScreenSize"
            android:launchMode="singleTop"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" />
        <activity
            android:name="com.vungle.warren.ui.VungleFlexViewActivity"
            android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize|screenLayout|smallestScreenSize"
            android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
            android:launchMode="singleTop"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar" />

        <!-- Amazon Payment Stuff -->
        <receiver
            android:name="com.amazon.device.iap.ResponseReceiver"
            tools:ignore="ExportedReceiver,InvalidPermission">
            <intent-filter>
                <action
                    android:name="com.amazon.inapp.purchasing.NOTIFY"
                    android:permission="com.amazon.inapp.purchasing.Permission.NOTIFY" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
        <!--Google Push Notifications Stuff-->
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

        <service
            android:name="mypackagename.notification.service.MyFirebaseMessagingService"
            android:exported="false">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>

        <!--End of Google Push Notifications Stuff-->

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.games.APP_ID"
            android:value="@string/google_game_app_id" />
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.appstate.APP_ID"
            android:value="@string/google_game_app_id" />

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.APPLICATION_ID"
            android:value="@string/ad_mob_app_id" />

        <meta-data
            android:name="applovin.sdk.key"
            android:value="DpAUIPAz0TKP6geC6ifl0HJdoW6brFg23rXLFhJFAdeGJHTP_78_OScAzknpzSs0HNMW4fnEHQVahz_h48gTaI" />

        <!-- Facebook Stuff-->

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId"
            android:value="@string/facebook_app_id" />

        <activity
            android:name="com.facebook.FacebookActivity"
            android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|screenLayout|screenSize|orientation"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar"
            tools:replace="android:theme" />

        <activity
            android:name="com.facebook.ads.AudienceNetworkActivity"
            android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize" />

        <activity
            android:name="com.facebook.CustomTabActivity"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

                <data android:scheme="@string/fb_login_protocol_scheme" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <!-- End of Facebook Stuff-->


        <!-- Tapjoy Stuff-->
        <activity
            android:name="com.tapjoy.TJAdUnitActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
            android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" />
        <activity
            android:name="com.tapjoy.mraid.view.ActionHandler"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden" />
        <activity
            android:name="com.tapjoy.mraid.view.Browser"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden" />
        <!-- For SDK 11.3+ -->
        <activity
            android:name="com.tapjoy.TJContentActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
            android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar" />
        <!--End of Tapjoy Stuff-->

        <!--Bugsnag Stuff-->
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.bugsnag.android.API_KEY"
            android:value="8117a06b5900bdf6c3d33f8150131fbb" />
        <!--End of Bugsnag Stuff-->

        <!--Ad Stuff-->
        <activity
            android:name="com.adcolony.sdk.AdColonyInterstitialActivity"
            android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
            android:hardwareAccelerated="true" />

        <activity
            android:name="com.applovin.adview.AppLovinInterstitialActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"/>

        <service android:name=".expansion.ExpansionFilesDownloaderService" />

        <receiver android:name=".expansion.DownloaderServiceBroadcastReceiver" />
        <receiver android:name=".notification.service.NotificationPublisher" />
        <!--End of Ad Stuff-->

        <receiver
            android:name="com.appsflyer.SingleInstallBroadcastReceiver"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.android.vending.INSTALL_REFERRER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

2. I used the device Id for the restoring the game progress before, so that means , that I have device id's in my DB and use them , if user reinstall the game. Now , if the previous problem will be resolved, how can I avoid loosing my users progress? I mean if I will get another id for user , then it will no longer the same as in DB.

Thanks guys.

=====EDIT=====

Here is screenshot from my Merged Manifest file, and I can't either navigate or remove it.

[image: Part of merged manifest, where the READ_PHONE_STATE is present]

======EDIT 2======

I found it, some of my libs have minSDKversion < 4, and this permission added automatically.

Comment: "Event If I remove the uses_permission row in manifest and remove the java code, my app continues to want the Phone State permission. Why? " -- because some library is requesting that permission. Check the "Merged Manifest" tab in the manifest editor in Android Studio.

Comment: @CommonsWare Hi. Thanks. Ok, now I see the permission in the Merged Manifest. But, could you please help me? how can I see what library uses that permission? When I click on a "Go to declaration" on any of the permissions, it navigates me to my main Manifest file, and also the "remove this line" function is disabled for this row. 

Please check my question, I've added a screenshot from my Merged Manifest file.

Comment: "how can I see what library uses that permission?" -- in the "Merged Manifest" tab, everything is color-coded, with a legend mapping colors to libraries. Unfortunately, it may be a bit difficult to distinguish one color from another. :-(

Comment: @CommonsWare it seems I found. There is an information in the bottom of the right side of merged manifest, when you tap on each row on the left side. It shows you from where the row merged or added. In case of READ_PHONE_STATE it shows me the following. 
```
implied from the android main manifest, line 1; reason: com.android.installreferrer has targetSdkVersion < 4
```

So , I'm going to check the installreferrer library.

Comment: That library must be *very* old to have a `targetSdkVersion` that low.

Comment: Is the problem solved? how did you solve the issue? I am facing the same while trying to fetch deviceId in a specific Xiomi fold device.